# Enter Condition Value using Excel User Form

Tags: excel, forms, userform

I am trying to code a user form to add entered values in the row associated with a specified value. I want a form to appear with two text boxes "Task Name" and "Task Quantity".

I then want excel to search a column that is specified with an input box "Task Column" (usually a or B) then paste the value from the user form "Task Quantity" in the column specified with another input box "Unit Column"

[User Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Ce0.png)

Here is my code so far:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim tskCol As String
        tskCol = Application.InputBox("Enter Column Letter for Task Names", , , , , , , 2)
    Dim unitCol As String
        unitCol = Application.InputBox("Enter Column for Number of Units", , , , , , , 2)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    LastRow = Range("tskCol" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'Copy input values to sheet.
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Range("tskCol" & i).Value = Me.txtTask Then
            Range("unitCol" & i).Replace What:="", Replacement:=Me.txtQuantity, LookAt:=xlPart _
            , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        End If
    Next i

    'Clear input controls.
    Me.txtTask.Value = ""
    Me.txtQuantity.Value = ""


End Sub
```

**Edited code**

```
    Option Explicit
Public tskCol As String
Public unitCol As String
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    tskCol = Application.InputBox("Enter Column Letter for Task Names", , , , , , , 2)
    unitCol = Application.InputBox("Enter Column for Number of Units", , , , , , , 2)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(tskCol & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'Copy input values to sheet.
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If ActiveSheet.Range(tskCol & i).Value = Me.txtTask Then
            ActiveSheet.Range(unitCol & i).Value = Me.txtQuantity.Value
        End If
    Next i

    'Clear input controls.
    Me.txtTask.Value = ""
    Me.txtQuantity.Value = ""


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using **Replace**?  Can you not just set the value:

```
If cStr(ActiveSheet.Range(tskCol & i).Value) = cStr(Me.txtTask) Then
    ActiveSheet.Range(unitCol & i).Value = Me.txtQuantity.Value
End If
```

**{EDIT}**  Just noticed that you have defined your Variables tskCol and unitCol in a Sub.  As soon as the Sub ends, these are wiped from memory.  You should be initialising them outside the Sub, at the start of the code module.

```
Option Explicit 'This line, which you can enable by default, means that any variable you have not defined will result in an error.  ALWAYS INCLUDE IT
Private tskCol As String 'Private means only code in this module can see/ use it
Private unitCol As String 'Any Sub or Function can in this module can now use these variables
```

**{EDIT: Full Code}**

```
Option Explicit
Private tskCol As String
Private unitCol AS String

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    tskCol = Application.InputBox("Enter Column Letter for Task Names", Type:=2)
    unitCol = Application.InputBox("Enter Column for Number of Units", Type:=2)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(tskCol & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'Copy input values to sheet.
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If cStr(ActiveSheet.Range(tskCol & i).Value) = cStr(Me.txtTask.Value) Then
            ActiveSheet.Range(unitCol & i).Value = Me.txtQuantity.Value
        End If
    Next i

    'Clear input controls.
    Me.txtTask.Value = ""
    Me.txtQuantity.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: I did try that too, but I keep getting a run-time error '1004': "Method 'Range' of ojbect'_Gobal' failed with occurs on my "LastRow" line

Comment: Ah - is the code running in a Module, in the UserForm, or from a Worksheet?  You may need to specify the worksheet, i.e. `Sheet1.Range("unitCol" & i")`

Comment: I have the code running in the form. I would like to be able to run in any activesheet

Comment: Okay, so you just need to use the special sheet object `ActiveSheet` then - I have updated the code to include this

Comment: hmm still getting the same error. error disappears when i replace the variable names with column letters but I still don't get a result

Comment: Ah - that's what I get for copying/pasting.  Do not put quotes around your variable names, because that just makes it a string instead.  Also, you have defined your variables in the wrong place!  Big edit to answer.

Comment: Good catch! Yea, I realized the variable where in different sub, but I thought because I made it public I could call them. My issue is I want the variables defined with the input boxes upon initialize then not have to repeat them every time I add a unit. aka cmdAdd_click

Comment: So, define them with Private before you start any Sub or Function - see MSDN for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declaring-variables

Comment: Thank you! that is what I was looking for. 

Seems we solved the error, but now it doesn't seem to set the value with form info :(

I'll update the code in the original post

Comment: Seems it works for text, but when the task name is a number and I enter a number in the txtTask box it doesn't work

Comment: Use cStr(..) to force both to evaluate as Strings.  "1" <> 1